# Calculating displacement in 3d projectile motion with magnus force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors, projectile

I am trying to calculate the displacement in x-z plane in 3D projectile motion of a rotating object where the force generated due to the magnus effect is applicable. The magnus force constitutes of a cross product between the unit vectors of the angular velocity ($\vec{w}$) and linear velocity ($\vec{V}$).

$$
F_M=[\rho AC_LV^2(\hat{w} \times \hat{V})]/2
$$

In the above equation, angular velocity is a variable vector while all other values are constant. The direction of the force changes throughout the projectile motion due to the changing velocity and hence using the standard equations for projectile motion would not give an accurate value for the displacement in x-z plane. In such a case, how would you calculate the displacement in x-z plane?

Answer (score 0):

If the projectile and the gun barrel are well designed, the angular velocity $\boldsymbol\omega(t)$ and the velocity $\mathbf{v}(t)$ of the projectile are aligned in the same direction of the axis of the projectile itself, and thus

$\mathbf{F}_M = \dfrac{1}{2} \rho A V^2 C_L \underbrace{\boldsymbol{\hat{\omega}} \times \mathbf{\hat{v}}}_{=\mathbf{0}} = \mathbf{0}$

Comment: This is not generally the case though.  Unlike an arrow or other projectile that tends to be tractable by virtue of having an aft CP, a bullet nearly always has a CP forward of the CG.  Thus the spin stabilization, thus less tractability, thus slightly increasing “nose high” angle of incidence as the bullet deepens in its descending leg…  which is what gives rise to the Magnus that must be calculated.  It is very small, normally to the left, and much smaller than gyroscopic forces to the right.  But it is non-zero, and increases as a function of time-of-flight.

Comment: oh, thanks. So I'll need to gather some info, learn something about guns, and edit my answer